# Passport no envia datos a la hora de registrar

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, passport

estoy intentando crear un login basado en node.js mongodb y con el método de autentificación de passport y tengo el problema de que a la hora de hacer el post. Se queda el navegador esperando y no lleva a ningún lado. El código es el siguiente

//Archivo de rutas

```
const express= require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const user = require('./models/user');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) =>{
    res.render('index', {
      message: req.flash('indexMessage')
    });
});

router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-registro',{
  successRedirect: '/inicio',
  failureRedirect:'/register',
  passReqToCallback: true
}));

router.get('/register', (req, res, next) =>{
  res.render('registro',{
    message: req.flash('registroMessage')});
});

router.post('/register', (req, res, next) =>{
  console.log(req.body);
});


router.get('/inicio', (req, res, next) =>{
  res.render('inicio',{
    message: req.flash('inicioMessage')});
});

module.exports= router;
```

// Archivo de passport

```
const passport= require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const User = require('../app/models/user');


    passport.serializeUser((user, done) =>{
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    
    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) =>{
        const user = await User.findById(id, (err,user)=>{
            if(err){
                console.error('There was an error in the process.')
            }
        });
        done (null, user);
    });
 passport.use('local-registro', new LocalStrategy({

        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    async (req, email, password, done) =>{
        
        const user = new User();
        user.email = email;
        user.password= password;
        await user.save();
        done(null, user);
    }));
```

//Archivo de servidor

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const passport = require("passport");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require("express-session");

const engine = require('ejs-mate');

require('./config/database');

require("./config/passport");

//Settings

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//Middlewares

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));//<-- el extended false indica que los datos del formulario que vamos a enviar en nuestra registro no reciben imagenes, solo envian datos simples;
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "lossecretos",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

//Routes
app.use('/', require('./app/routes'));


//Static files

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log("server on port", app.get("port"));
});
```

//Archivo database

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const { mongodb } = require('./keys');

mongoose.connect(mongodb.URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then (db =>console.log('Database is connected'))
    .catch(err=> console.error(err));
```

He probado a ver si el problema venia a que no se conectaba correctamente a la base de datos creada en mongodb... en principio no deberia de ese el problema, sencillamente a la hora de registrar se queda pensando y al cabo de un rato me devuelve: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Si alguien me echara un cable se lo agradeceria mil porque me he quedado sin ideas ya. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Según tu código, el problema lo tienes en el archivo de `passport`, ya que en el método `passport.deserializeUser` estas mezclando `callback` con `async/await` y por eso no devuelve el usuario y se queda la promesa pendiente de resolver.

Te muestro el código:

```
 // Opción 1: callback

    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) =>{
        User.findById(id, (err,user)=>{
            if(err) console.error('There was an error in the process.')
            done (err, user);
        });
    });


 // Opción 2: async/await

    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) =>{
        try{
          const user = await User.findById(id);
          done(null, user)
        } catch(e){
          console.error('There was an error in the process.')
          done(e, null)
        }
    });
```

Espero que esta respuesta te ayude a resolver el problema.

Cualquier cosa avisa de nuevo.

Un saludo